# Object labels "from 0 to num_classes-1" or from "1 to num_classes" in built in image object detection on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api, gcp-ai-platform-training

The Google [built-in object detection documentation/reference](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/reference/object-detection) says the the `num_classes` argument should be set as follows:

> E.g., for **num_classes=5**, the range of image/class/label in input tf.Example needs to be **[0, 4]**.

Yet, most other resources (e.g., [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md)) on how to create your own dataset in the object detection API world say that labels should start with 1, that is, for 5 classes they should be [1,5].

My questions are:

Is the example in the reference documentation correct, that is, should I use [0,4] for 5 classes?

Does it matter at all, i.e., can this break the training procedure?

Is the "built-in object detection" algorithm special in other ways or can I follow the "[using your own dataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md)" function to create my TFrecord files?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I opened an issue in the TF repo on their documentation saying labels should start with value 1 (instead of saying 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the labels should be [1,5].
The documentation has changed :)

See the updated [documnetation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/reference/object-detection)
under --> Hyperparameters --> num_classes